# Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code in unity andorid build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, tensorflow

I have implement Tensorflow Android as a unity plugin. After building aar and integrate to Unity project, i get error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_162.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-4.0.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m" "assembleRelease"

stderr[
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: Dex cannot parse version 52 byte code.
This is caused by library dependencies that have been compiled using Java 8 or above.
If you are using the 'java' gradle plugin in a library submodule add 
targetCompatibility = '1.7'
sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
to that submodule's build.gradle
```

I have got aar tensorflow file in: https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/tensorflow/tensorflow-android/1.8.0/
and copy to Assets/Plugin but it still get this error.
I am stuck in a day and can not come out problem.

Comment: Install JDK 1.8 and remove older JDK instances

Comment: my version java already is  "1.8.0_162"

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade tensorflow to 1.4 it works for me. Another solution is using Tensorflow sharp unity